# VNC 'resize remote session to local window' on Debian (Xtightvnc)

Tags: debian, vnc, tightvnc

I currently trying to migrate from Centos7 to Debian10, but I'm blocked by a different default VNC behaviour.

I'm using TigerVncViewer on my Windows and osx clients to connect to my server, and it has a feature called '**resize remote session to local window**'.  This means that when the TigerVncViewer appliaction window is resized on the client, the remote screen on the vncserver is resized automatically to the same shape/resolution.

This works beautifully out of the box for Centos 7.  However, when I connect to a remote Debian 10 server the session remains a fixed size, reshaping the local TigerVncViewer window does not change it.

I noticed that Centos7 uses Xnvc under the hood, while Debian10 runs a process called Xtightvnc, perhaps that is why?

Does anyone know how to get this VNC auto-resizing feature to work on Debian10, do I need to change some config, or pass a some different args to Xtightvnc when it is started up via the vncserver wrapper?  On some of the forums that I searched, people suggest that tightvnc does supports this feature, but it's just not obvious how to enable it.

If anyone is interested, I followed these instructions for to set-up [a VNC server on Centos7](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-centos-7/)
and these instructions [for Debian10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-10)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution to the problem.

The problem is was that

```
$ sudo apt install tightvncserver
```

will cause Xtightvnc to be invoked instead of Xvnc when the vncserver is started.
Xtightvnc does not currently support the AcceptSetDesktopSize option.

However, Xtigervnc does support this option and vncviewer will be configured to use this when it instead of Xtightvnc by additionally installing these additional packages:

```
$ sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-common
```

Now the '**resize remote session to local window**' feature on the viewer is supported by the vncserver.